# Lower bounds for totient function of a Carmichael number

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, totient-function, pseudoprimes, carmichael-numbers

**Short version**: I am wondering if there are any good bounds of the form $\phi(n) \geq f(n)\cdot n$ with $f(n)$ close to 1 for high $n$, optionally under the assumption that $n$ is a Carmichael number.

**Long version:** Consider Fermat's test in the following form for an odd integer $n>2$:

1. choose $a$ from $\{2, \ldots, n - 1\}$ uniformly at random
2. return ‘Prime’ if $[a^{n-1} = 1]\ (\text{mod}\ n)$ and ‘Composite’ otherwise

For a Carmichael number, this test incorrectly returns ‘Prime’ if and only if $a$ and $n$ are coprime, i.e. with probability
$\frac{\varphi(n)-1}{n - 2}$. In textbooks, it is suggested that this number is far too high to use Fermat's test as a prime test for a Carmichael number, but I was wondering if there are any good concrete bounds for this probability that support this claim.

Comment: There appear to be many Carmichael numbers divisible by $7$, and for those $\phi(n)\leq \frac{6}{7}n$.

Comment: If the given $n$ is a Carmichael-number with $3$ distinct large prime factors, then , the probability that the test fails, is almost $1$. We have a better situation, when th Carmichael number has many small prime factors. But since the first step to test the primality of a number is checking for small prime factors, this case is of little practical interest. In the case, you want to improve the Fermat-test, google strong-Fermat-test, which is only slightly more complicated and much more reliable.

Comment: No, I'm really just interested in evaluating *how bad* the error probability is. I was hoping for something like ‘$\phi(n)/n$ is close to 1 for all/most Carmichael numbers $n$’, but what you said about it being close to 1 unless it has large prime factors and the case of small factors being uninteresting anyway does make sense. Thanks!

Comment: Of course, then it would be interesting to know just how many Carmichael numbers with few and big prime factors there are. But I suppose that's difficult to quantify.

Comment: Often, for the random base $a$ with $1<a<n$ , it is first checked whether $\ \gcd(a,n)\ne 1\ $, in which case we have found a non-trivial factor. In this sense, Carmichael numbers will fail with probability $1$.